# Converting letters in javascript - Who can see my error?

Tags: javascript

Deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA) is a chemical found in the nucleus of cells and carries the "instructions" for the development and functioning of living organisms.

In DNA strings, symbols "A" and "T" are complements of each other, as "C" and "G". You have function with one side of the DNA (string, except for Haskell); you need to get the other complementary side. DNA strand is never empty or there is no DNA at all (again, except for Haskell).

More similar exercise are found here http://rosalind.info/problems/list-view/ (source)
DNAStrand ("ATTGC") // return "TAACG"
DNAStrand ("GTAT") // return "CATA"

```
function DNAStrand(dna){
  let arr = dna.split("")
  console.log(arr)
  let newarr = []
  for(var i=0;i<arr[i];i++){
    if(arr[i] == "A"){
      newarr.push("T")
    } else if (arr[i] == "T"){
      newarr.push("A")
    } else if (arr[i] == "C"){
      newarr.push("G")
    } else if (arr[i] == "G"){
      newarr.push("C")
    }
  }
  console.log(newarr)
  return newarr.join("")
}

DNAStrand("ATTGC")
```

Comment: _"If you want to know more"_  I don't, nor is it relevant to your question

Comment: I would argue that an easier way to go about this is to iterate over the string itself, rather than separate every single character into an independent element of an array. Try initializing some string for returning, and then iterate over `dna` using something like `for (let c of dna) { /* append corresponding character to return string */ }`.

Answer (score 2):

`for(var i=0;i<arr[i];i++){`

change it to

`for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){`

#### EDIT

A better algorithm:

```
function DNAStrand(dna) {
    var letters = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C'};
    var arr = [];
    for (var i=0; i < dna.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = letters[dna[i]];
    }
    return arr.join('');
}
```

In javascript you can't edit a string (by assigning a character to a specific position of it), so I argue that the array solution is not bad. But looking at a dictionary of letters makes the solution better.

Comment: No problem @CharlieVdb.

Answer (score 0):

```
const DEFAULT = {
  A:'T',
  T:'A',
  C:'G',
  G:'C',
}
function DNAStrand(dna){
  const convert = [...dna].map(v=> {
    return v = DEFAULT[v] || '';
  })
  return convert.join("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function DNAStrand(dna)
{ 
dna = dna.split(""); 
    for(let i = 0; i < dna.length; i++)
    {
        if(dna[i] == 'T')
        {
            dna.splice(i,1,'A');
        }
        else if(dna[i] == 'A')
        {
            dna.splice(i,1,'T');
        }
        else if(dna[i] == 'C')
        {
            dna.splice(i,1,'G');
        }
        else
        {
            dna.splice(i,1,'C');
        }
    }
    dna = dna.join(''); 
    return dna;}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
const  DNAStrand = (dna)=>{
  const arr = dna.toLowerCase().split("")
  let output = ''
  for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]==="a"){
      arr[i] = 't'
      output +=arr[i]
    }
    else if(arr[i]==='t'){
      arr[i]='a'
      output +=arr[i]
    }
    else if(arr[i]==='c'){
    arr[i]='g'
    output +=arr[i]
    }
    else if(arr[i]==="g"){
    arr[i]='c'
    output +=arr[i]
    }
 }
 return output.toUpperCase()
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).